# PHP AJAX and mySQL not returning data?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following block of PHP:

```
$word = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['word']));
    $firstletter = substr('$word', 0, 1);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE word LIKE '%$firstletter'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error().": ".$query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    // send back the word to ajax request
    $i = 0;
    $fullLoad = '';
    while ($i < mysql_numrows($result)) {
        $fullLoad = $fullload . '|' . $row['word'];
        $i++;
    }
    echo $fullLoad;
```

Now, my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "word-list.php",
                data: "word="+ theword,
                success: function(data){ //data retrieved
                    console.log(data);
                            }
    });
```

Now, lets assume that the missing word variable is `apple` - so `$word = 'apple';`

But when the console.log() outputs - all I get is zero, nothing, nada, zip, blahblah

>:(

Comment: Does it work if you browse to word-list.php?word=apple?

Comment: no, I just get a blank window - no source :(

Comment: substr('$word', 0, 1);  is not the same as substr("$word", 0, 1);, if you substr '$word' between 0 and 1, the firstletter is $, if you substr "$word" or $word between 0 and 1, this can be different (a of apple or sth. like that), and if your DB returns null (because there is nothing with $) this is normal. Change '$word' to $word or "$word" ;)

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation (+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
 $firstletter = substr($word, 0, 1);
```

Comment: yeah. that it ;) '$word' != "$word" and $word ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by this logic here:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$i = 0;
$fullLoad = '';
while ($i < mysql_numrows($result)) {
    $fullLoad = $fullload . '|' . $row['word'];
    $i++;
}
echo $fullLoad;
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc` will only ever return one row.  Don't you mean:

```
$fullLoad = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if( !is_null( $row['word'] ) ) $fullLoad .= . '|' . $row['word'];
}
echo $fullLoad;
```

The first one will only ever output one result a number of different times.  The second example will output all of the values so long as a row's word value is not null.

Comment: oh man, I was JUST wondering why there was only one row! Thank you! Shame I can't accept two answers